# Value for map.compute is always null

Tags: java

I'm trying to use `.compute()` on my map but the `else` statement is never fired.

```
public void onInviteUser(int adapterPosition) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onInviteUser: " + adapterPosition); //not null
        mapInvitedFriends.compute(adapterPosition, (k, v) -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onInviteUser: " + adapterPosition); 
            if (v == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInviteUser: " + v);
                mapInvitedFriends.put(adapterPosition, listFriends.get(adapterPosition));
                Log.d(TAG, "onInviteUser: " + listFriends.get(adapterPosition).toString());
                return v;
            } else {
                //Never gets fired
                Log.d(TAG, "onInviteUser: " + v);
                mapInvitedFriends.remove(adapterPosition);
                return v;
            }
        });
}
```

I've logged everthing, but I can't figure out why the value `v` is always null.

Edit:

The types for the map is:

```
private final Map<Integer, Friend> mapInvitedFriends = new HashMap<>();
private final List<Friend> listFriends = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be really helpful here - you haven't told us anything about `mapInvitedFriends` - not even its type, or what's creating it.

Comment: added an edit to

Comment: Your `compute` method returns `null` when `v` is null, which means you're *never* creating a mapping...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not use `compute` correctly:

> The remapping function should not modify this map during computation.

Therefore you shouldn't call to `mapInvitedFriends.put` or `mapInvitedFriends.remove` inside the function.

Instead, you can try:

```
    mapInvitedFriends.compute(adapterPosition, (k, v) -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "onInviteUser: " + adapterPosition); 
        if (v == null) {
            return listFriends.get(adapterPosition); // this will cause a new mapping to be added
        } else {
            return null; // this will cause the existing mapping to be removed
        }
    });
```

or simply:

```
mapInvitedFriends.compute(adapterPosition,
                          (k, v) -> v == null ? listFriends.get(adapterPosition) : null);
```